# MS Access SQL - remove duplicates without distinct/group by

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am working in MS Access and need to remove duplicate values from the [ref] field without using distinct (unable to use on a specific field in access) and group by (as I want to group by [type]).

I have tried using an additional sub-query to de-dupe the [ref] field however have been unable to get this to work. The below code works however includes the duplicate values in the [ref] field.

```sql
SELECT
    switch(LEFT(t1.[type],1)='C',"Covers",LEFT(t1.[type],1)='P',"PIP") AS type
  , COUNT(t1.[ref])
  , COUNT(t2.[posted]) AS Total_posted
  , format(COUNT(t2.[posted]) / COUNT(t1.[ref]),"0.00%") AS Percentage_posted
FROM
    Some_Table AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                t2.[ID]
              , t2.[posted]
            FROM
                Some_Table AS t2
            WHERE
                t2.[posted] NOT LIKE ('NA')
        )
        AS t2
    ON
        t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
GROUP BY
    LEFT(t1.[type],1)
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: example scenario below

### t1.[ref]

- 1
- 1
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

Current code would return the COUNT of t1.[ref] as 7, however I want the output to return a count of 5.

Further Edit: Code now as below however t3.[ref] still not providing distinct values. Any idea where I am going wrong here?

```
    SELECT Switch(Left(t1.[type],1)='C',"Covers",Left(t1.[type],1)='P',"PIP") AS type, Count(t3.[ref]) AS CountOfref, Count(t2.[posted]) AS Total_posted, Format(Count(t2.[posted])/Count(t1.[ref]),"Percent") AS Percentage_posted
FROM (additional_data_fields AS t1 LEFT JOIN (Select t2.[ID],t2.[posted] from additional_data_fields as t2 where t2.[posted] not like ('NA'))  AS t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]) LEFT JOIN (select distinct t3.[ref] from additional_data_fields as t3)  AS t3 ON t1.[ref] = t3.[ref]
GROUP BY Left(t1.[type],1)
```

Comment: [type] isn't in your result set, so why would you want to group by it? Why not `GROUP BY Cohort`?

Comment: Gordon - apologies, further info added, hopefully that will help.

Comment: JNevill - Cohort should've been removed as an alias, amended now. Hope that helps, if you need more info just let me know - cheers.

Comment: In that case, perhaps `GROUP BY switch(LEFT(t1.[type],1)='C',"Covers",LEFT(t1.[type],1)='P',"PIP")`?

Comment: Jnevill - many thanks for the help but my issue is regarding t1.[ref]. I don't think the above would provide unique values for the t1.[ref] field?

Comment: I have now added updated code however still not achieving desired result. Any idea where I am going wrong @GordonLinoff ?